# Adding CoreData To An Existing Project

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to add CoreData to my project.
I added the `.xcdatamedeld` file to my project and copied these AppDelegate functions from another project I have opened initially with the "Use CoreData" box enabled.
Though, I'm getting some errors that says: `'NSPersistentContainer' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer`.
What am I supposed to do with versions older then iOS 10?

This is the code I Added to my `AppDelegate.swift` file:

```
import CoreData
  // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
         */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "testCoreData")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need the older way with `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`

Comment: but how will it suite for iOS 10 and above and iOS 9 and below?

Comment: `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { // use NSPersistentContainer } else { // use NSPersistentStoreCoordinator }`